# JSON response url formatting issue

Tags: php

I have a php file upload script which returns a json response. The issue is the url of the response contains odd characters.

I get a response that has \ / between the directories instead of just / or \ /\ / after the http: instead of just //

So I am getting this.
http:\ / \ /www.mywebsite.com\ /uploads\ /myfile.jpg

But I need it to look like this.
http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/myfile.jpg

Based on my code below any thoughts on what I need to change?

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_POST['album_name']))
{
$dir_name = $_POST['album_name'];
}
$json = array();
if(file_exists('uploads/'.$dir_name))
{
$handle = opendir('uploads/'.$dir_name);

while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
    {


        $url= 'http://www.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/uploads/'.$dir_name.'/'.$file;
    $data = array($type,$url);
        array_push($json,$data);
    }



}
}
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: Could you post the actual url are getting back?

Comment: I tried to but stackoverflow is actually reformatting it to look correct. I am getting a response like: http:\ / \ /www.mywebsite.com\ /uploads\ /myfile.jpg

Comment: And is the URL you are getting from json_encode or echo?

Comment: This issue is in the echo json_encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` to the json_encode options (available since PHP 5.4)

`echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the json_encode function. It automatically adds backslashes,
since in json it can cause problems if a `/` is after a `<`, since this is in HTML how you end a tag.

The best solution is probably to simply leave it as it is, and when parsing the JSON if the problem remains, that is if whatever json decoding method you use does not remove these backslashes, do a string replace, in php this would be `str_replace` 
[Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Hope this solves your problem :)